# Render image data in ejs with nodejs

Tags: node.js, base64, ejs

I have a nodejs express system, and want to render an image of a qr code datablock.

I am generating the image from my mongoose Schema

```
BaseUserSchema.methods.getProvisionImage = function getProvisionImage() {
    qr.toDataURL( JSON.stringify({
        account: this.accountName,
        code: this.provisionCode,
    }),
    {},
    function (err, url) {

        if (err) throw err;

        return url;
    });
};
```

and want to draw in an image on the page

```
<img class="img-thumbnail m-2 d-block"
     src="<% provisionUser.getProvisionImage() %>"
     title="Click to enlarge" >
```

The provisionUser is correct, and the value at the end of the generation code when I am debugging is

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAK ... [etc]  ... ==
```

This all looks pretty good to me - how do I convert that string into something that an  can display?

Answer (score 1):

Since `ejs` does not support asynchronous functions with callback your only way to get around it might be to use async/await.

You can try this:

```
BaseUserSchema.methods.getProvisionImage = async function getProvisionImage() {
    var data = '';
    try {
        data = await qr.toDataURL(JSON.stringify({
            account: this.accountName,
            code: this.provisionCode,
        }));
    } catch (e) {}
    return data;
};
```

**Edit**

```
// this function no longer needs to be async since i moved the async code to another async function
BaseUserSchema.methods.getProvisionImage = function getProvisionImage() {
    var data = getData(JSON.stringify({
        account: this.accountName,
        code: this.provisionCode,
    }));

    return data;
};

async function getDataURL(str) {
    var data = '';
    try {
        data = await qr.toDataURL(str);
    } catch (e) {}
    return data;
};
```

And to explain why you code can't work:

```
// the getProvisionImage function does not return anything
// since you do not have a return statement in the getProvisionImage scope
BaseUserSchema.methods.getProvisionImage = function getProvisionImage() {
    qr.toDataURL( JSON.stringify({
        account: this.accountName,
        code: this.provisionCode,
    }),
    {},
    function callback(err, url) { // this function is the scope of the return statement bellow

        if (err) throw err;
        // this will return a value to the caller of this function
        // not the caller of getProvisionImage
        return url;
    });
    
    // this return will work, not the above one in the callback function
    return 'data:image/png;bas....';
};
```

Comment: Great explanation. Still getting (when I look at page source) <img class="img-thumbnail m-2 d-block" src="[object Promise]" title="Click to enlarge">

Comment: Oh, of course, i didn't realize you need to call it with `await` like so `<% await provisionUser.getProvisionImage() %>` but i'm not sure if thats gonna work. See my edit in the answer for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

try promisifying the method, and then await the result into a variable which will be passed to `ejs`:

```
BaseUserSchema.methods.getProvisionImage = function getProvisionImage() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
        qr.toDataURL(JSON.stringify({
                account: this.accountName,
                code: this.provisionCode,
            }), {},
            function(err, url) {

                if (err) reject(err);

                resolve(url);
            });
    });
};

//...

const img = await provisionUser.getProvisionImage();

//...
src="<% img %>"
```